# Calculate Field based on two fields using python

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, field-calculator

I'm trying to calculate new values for a field based on two other fields. In VB I don't have any problem, but I need to use python to publish my gp service.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Comment: You do not say the error returned but I think the problem is that you are using "= =" when it should be "==" (in two places).

Comment: I'm also not sure how well Field Calculator handles the `ó` in `Dirección`. Perhaps try a standard `o` instead?

Comment: It's also not clear whether you have been inconsistent with your indent levels.  To me it looks like a one space indent before `if` and two more spaces before `return`.

Answer (score 2):

Taking account of the comments by @nmpeterson and myself against your question, I would try the following:

Pre-logic Script Code:

```
def a(Riesgo,Direccion):
    if (Riesgo == "Alto" and Direccion == "Sur"):
        return "Sur"
```

Mensaje =

```
a(!Riesgo!,!Dirección!)
```